# Is it possible to mount DriveImage XML backup image?

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, mount, ntfs

I used DriveImage XML [1] to create backup of the harddrive on some old Desktop PC with NTFS partition.  I used no compression (None), enabled Raw, Split Files (I should not check this) and create the backup image.

Then I joint all files to one big image file on Linux like this:

```
cat disk_C.dat disk_C.001 disk_C.002 ... > diskC.img
```

Looking at the img file I see there are bytes at 512 offset

```
Hex  : EB 52 90 4E 54 46 53 20
ASCII: __  R __  N  T  F  S
```

Trying to mount it:

```
sudo mount -o loop,ro,offset=512 drive.img /mnt/diskC
```

Gives following error

```
Failed to read last sector (80276741): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/loop0': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/loop0' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Any ideas if it is actually possible to mount the image created by DriveImage XML?

[1] http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm

Comment: is this a multi-partition drive?

Comment: nope, just one partition